# Which types of data sets can I use for sentiment analysis?

Tags: facebook, dataset, project, sentiment-analysis, social-media

I want unique dataset for sentiment analysis. Please suggest which dataset would be best for me. Whose accuracy is low or not available?

I'm trying Fiverr and Facebook-related datasets. I don't know, am I right or wrong? But I guess, I haven't found data on Fiverr or Facebook that is available or has good accuracy.